# Is State hoisting and lifting the state in REACT the same thing?

Tags: reactjs

Is the process of moving the state up (lifting the state) into a common ancestor component the same thing as state hoisting?

Comment: FYI-- [the word "hoisting" has some history in JS and historically refers to the hoisting of `var` and `function` declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).  Just make sure you aren't conflating those two things when talking about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, https://reactpatterns.js.org/docs/state-hoisting/

> As the example above you are encouraged to lift state up, if two
> components need to act on the same data or need to use the same
> callback.
>
> So you should create a common ancestor in this common ancestor and
> then use the state to manage all the data and callbacks that children
> will use in rendering as following.

Also this - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html